# Titanium Change event not firing the first time with picker

Tags: android, ios, events, titanium, picker

I am making an iOS and Android app using Titanium Classic. I am fairly new to Titanium but I have some experience using Javascript. The app will have a window where the user and select from a picker an amount of time in hours and minutes. The selection will be saved and be used later to send a notification to the user that the time they selected is up. I am currently using Titanium's picker function with the type of "count down timer." However, I am having trouble getting the change event to work when the user selects a different time. It also will show the last selected time when I try going to a different window and entering the timer window again.

My question is how can I get the change event to fire the first time the user selects a different number? 
In follow up to my question, is there a better way to save the picker selection for later use?

Here is the code for the picker:

```
    var hours = 0;
    var minutes = 1;
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor: '#A6B97B',
    layout: 'horizontal'
});     
    var picker = Ti.UI.createPicker({
    type:Ti.UI.PICKER_TYPE_COUNT_DOWN_TIMER,
    top:2,
    width: '50%',
    height: '20%'
});

    picker.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
Ti.App.Properties.setInt('countDownDuration', e.countDownDuration);

if (e.countDownDuration >= 3600000)
    {
hours = Math.floor(Ti.App.Properties.getInt('countDownDuration')/3600000);
    minutes = Math.floor(Ti.App.Properties.getInt('countDownDuration')/60000 -   (hours*60));
    }

else {
    minutes = Math.floor(Ti.App.Properties.getInt('countDownDuration')/60000);
    hours = 0;  
}
    });

    var doneBtn = Ti.UI.createButton({
      title : 'Get Value',
      height : '15%',
      width : '30%'
    });

   doneBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
     // get value
     if(hours > 0){
     alert('You set the time estimate to ' + hours + ' hours and ' + minutes+ '  minutes');
    }
   else {
     alert('You set the time estimate to ' + minutes + ' minutes');
}
});
```

If anyone has any advice on how to get the change event to fire the first time, I would really appreciate it. Also, if you know a better way to accomplish saving data from the picker for use later, that would be helpful as well.

Thanks!

Jessica

Comment: tip: Titanium.UI.PICKER_TYPE_COUNT_DOWN_TIMER only work on iphone and ipad.
at this time i do not have mac to test on ios.

Comment: try this for android...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32883221/picker-change-event-not-firing-for-first-time-in-titanium